# SELECT em um período de tempo em uma coluna datetime

Tags: sql, mysqli, sqlite, phpmyadmin

Eu tenho a seguinte coluna

```
id datareg
1  2020-07-24 08:00:00
2  2020-07-24 08:30:00
3  2020-07-24 08:45:00
4  2020-07-24 09:00:00
5  2020-07-24 13:00:00
```

Eu preciso de uma consulta que me retorne a QUANTIDADE de registros dentro de um intervalo de tempo, por exemplo, das 08h as 09h. Estou fazendo a consulta dessa forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) from TABLE 
WHERE datareg BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00'
```

E ele me retorna que eu tenho um total de ZERO registros. O que eu estou errando na linha de consulta?

Comment: Mas o seu campo não é do tipo DATETIME? Separe apenas a parte do TIME.

Comment: Sim, o datareg é do tipo DATETIME

Comment: pode usar 'cast(datareg as date)' ou 'date(datareg)'

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) from TABLE 
WHERE TIME(datareg) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00'`.